# New problem with rendering in Chrome, Vivaldi and Opera ... video driver issue?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, google-chrome, opera, vivaldi

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.2 on a machine with NVIDIA Corporation GA106M [GeForce RTX 3060 Mobile / Max-Q] (rev a1). This morning, as usual, I ran the Ubuntu Software Updater, which installed some changes.  I didn't look very carefully at what: my bad, I did see it updated Thunderbird but that's fine.

Now I find that Chrome, Vivaldi and Opera are hopelessly failing to render pretty much any page and none of them will launch their settings interface usefully: all three just show a blank so I can't change anything in the browsers.  Same in incognito mode in Chrome.

Every other piece of software I am using seems to be fine including Firefox.  Running Chrome in my Windows 10 in a VirtualBox VM on the machine is also fine.

I conclude this is almost certainly some nasty corner case involving the rendering engines of these browsers (I think they all use the same one don't they?) and something that has changed in the Ubuntu video drivers.  It's a pain as use all four browsers normally to keep different work on the web separate.  Is anyone else seeing this or similar?

Answer (score 3):

what worked for me was a temporary solution of running Opera/Chrome with the --disable-gpu option

@Edit delete folder ~/.config/google-chrome/Default/GPUCache (for opera is ~/.config/opera/GPUCache) fix problems with GPU rendering

Comment: Removing the cache folder fixed the problem for me with AMD integrated graphics.

Answer (score 0):

I found same issue today in my Chrome browser.
I fixed it by disabling option "Use hardware acceleration when available" in settings and relaunching.

Answer (score 0):

I run into the same problem with AMD Ryzen Pro 7, without nvidia, on Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS.

To fix it, locate your google chrome

```
$ which google-chrome
/usr/bin/google-chrome
```

Now if you run it from the cli without any flags, you will see a huge stacktrace.

```
$ /usr/bin/google-chrome
```

To fix it, disable gpu compositing.

```
$ /usr/bin/google-chrome --disable-gpu-compositing
```

Now, go to chrome://settings/system (Settings -> System) and disable `use hardware acceleration when available` toggle.

You can close chrome and start it normally now.

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04, Radeon, Chrom Version 114.0.5735.198 (Official Build) (64-bit) Disabling Hardware Acceleration fixed the issue, albeit at the cost of not having this HA... which is a fairly significant issue for me. Anyway, seems like various people are having this problem

Comment: I (original post person!) can confirm that this fixed things for me.   I can also confirm that following the same procedure fixed things for Vivaldi and Opera.  Excellent.  Many thanks.

Comment: chrome-flag: `#enable-vulkan = Enabled` seemed to solve this for me, so at least hardware acceleration is functional.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76261884/webgpu-cant-be-enabled-on-chrome-v113 Interestingly this also solved the issue of graphics rendering for me while keeping Hardware rendering), albeit running with an unsupported flag
`google-chrome-stable --enable-unsafe-webgpu --enable-features=Vulkan`

looks like webgpu is default in v113 but isn't supported on platforms outside Windows, ChromeOS and MacOS :-(